# Broadcast receiver for (any) active network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Time has come to learn how to implement a broadcast receiver for the first time. :)

I found this great example for a [WiFi Scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050101/wifi-scan-results-broadcast-receiver-not-working/7050155#7050155) broadcast receiver, but that's too WiFi detail oriented. All I need is a Boolean notification that tells me whether ***any*** active network has been found.

Is there a particular such broadcast?

Is there a compilation/list of all system generated broadcasts?

Comment: This might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available

Comment: @androidnoob Thanks +1. The link you brought is very helpful, but if I understand correctly, it could only be used for *polling*. What I am interested in is some kind of listener or broadcast receiver sits idle until waken up by the event. Do you think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179906/how-can-i-receive-a-notification-when-the-device-loses-network-connectivity) can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/android-network-connectivity-broadcastreceiver/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176570/checking-the-networking-connectivity-using-broadcastreceiver-in-android)

In case the pages pointed by the links ever goes down, here is the key:

> register a BroadcastReciver with action
>   **ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**.