# How my android application will be notified whenever the internet connection will not be available?

Tags: android, events

My requirement is that a piece of code should be triggered immediately whenever internet connection gets unavailable. Is there a way to do it in android?

Comment: yes its possible, what you have tried so far to check internet connection.

Comment: ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     if (ni!=null && ni.isAvailable() && ni.isConnected()) {
         return true;
     } else {
         return false; 
     }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **BroadCastReceiver**
see the following link

[Checking the Networking Connectivity using BroadcastReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176570/checking-the-networking-connectivity-using-broadcastreceiver-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the android SDK.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html
you can use the PhoneState listener to look for data connection state changes

Comment: Will this also check for internet connection through Wifi?

Comment: no then you will have to look into the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static Boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

the function will return false if there is no internet or working data connection ....