# Network Check in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to handle network check by BroadcastReceiver for any application, I know how to check network availability when i am calling my services but suppose my network get disconnected in between transaction I can not handle this situation.

Please provide some tutorial link also where i can learn this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BroadcastReceiver networkStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w("Network Listener", "Network Type Changed");
}
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);        
registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);
```

This is a [example code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java).

Answer (score 3):

Use this :-

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cmanager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        NetworkInfo netInformation= cmanager .getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
        if (netInformation!= null && netInformation.isAvailable() && netInformation.isConnected()) 
        { 
            return true; 
        }
        return false; 
    }
```

or check this:-

> [Checking the Networking Connectivity using BroadcastReceiver in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176570/checking-the-networking-connectivity-using-broadcastreceiver-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

u can also add info.isConnectedOrConnecting() option like this..

```
public static boolean checkConn(Context ctx)
{
    ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable()||!info.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Internet is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code I found here on Stackoverflow (don't remember who wrote it)

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return info.isConnected();
}
```

requires `internet` and `network_state` permissions

Comment: the first answer is also same, this code can just check network availability and as i mentioned in my question i know how to check network availability, my above posted answer works fine for me.