# Android 6.0 Broadcast Receiver don't receive BOOT_COMPLETE

Tags: java, android, xml, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow

My receiver is not working with `Android 6.0 Marshmallow`.

I am sending a broadcast through adb shell, see below:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` received
if application was open, App say:Working!

But if the application was not open, it has not been returning anything.

My code is here;

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.berate.rebootreceiverfromb3r0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:protectionLevel="signature|development"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.berate.rebootreceiverfromb3r0.Yakala_Receiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Receiver.Java;

```
public class Yakala_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"i got it ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Edit: I have very interesting info, My code is working on samsung (Android 6.0) devices. But my (Android 6.0) devices not responding me

Comment: Add android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" in your receiver tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274997/why-broadcastreceiver-works-even-when-app-is-in-background check out

Comment: Why are you specifying the android:protectionLevel? This is when you create a permissions not when you're using a permission.

Comment: @JoxTraex i forgot delete it. My code is not have protectionlevel, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed, some new android devices have security application by default. some times these apps lock your auto-start mode.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: My mobile phone has security application. i did remove security application and my code working without a problem. you should search third party security app on your mobile phone.

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.berate.rebootreceiverfromb3r0.Yakala_Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

to this

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.berate.rebootreceiverfromb3r0.Yakala_Receiver"  android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

hope it helps

Comment: You will need to open the app once to receive broadcast check this for more info -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/19856367/1129332

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my problem is not here, im opening app and dont remove. im closing app and trying send broadcast. and app not response.

Comment: I have very interesting info, My code is working on samsung (Android 6.0) devices. But my (Android 6.0) devices not responding me.
what do you think this is a special issue?

Comment: some new android devices have security application by default. some times these apps lock your auto-start mode can you please check in settings it may be preventing boot broadcast receiver ?

Comment: i checked this. My phone is not have security app.