# Android 6 preventing boot complete broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

My app stopped receiving boot broadcasting on Android 6 (it is working fine on Android 5).

I noticed in the log that the broadcast is being prevented:

```
I/BackgroundManagerService: prevent from boot complete broadcast: com.mycompany.app
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
...     
         <receiver android:name="plugin.kiosk.BootService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
...
</application>
```

My app package name is : com.mycompany.app and my broadcast class is under a different package (plugin.kiosk).

Has anyone seen that problem? Any clues?

Update: I already tried changing to:

```
<receiver android:name="plugin.kiosk.BootService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" >
```

but same problem.

Update 2: Tried to add new action (below) and same issue.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Comment: try to add android:enabled="true" in <receiver

Comment: No success. Same issue.

Comment: which device you using?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Dejvid, I was able to identify that my code was fine and it was something with my tablet.

Indeed I tried my code on another tablet and it all worked.

So, I am guessing there is a strange process on my original tablet that is preventing the broadcasting.

Comment: test with signed apk. some device do not allow service/receiver in debug app

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` permission in your manifest?

Comment: @rsc does your broadcast extend BroadcastReceiver? I mean in the java code.

Comment: @rsc It is really weird. I have read somewhere that "After installing your app, it needs to be lunch at least once, manually by the user, in order to receive Boot complete event." Have you lunched your app at least once?

Comment: Yes, I read that also. And yes, I opened after I install it and if I simulate the broadcast via adb it opens the app. But If I reboot the tablet, it will not receive the broadcast. I am wondering if it is something on the tablet that is blocking the broadcast (based on the logcat message)

Comment: @rsc Finally, I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41808865/7836497) that new android devices have security application by default. some times these apps lock your auto-start mode.

Comment: You can see in the comments that I talked with that guy already. I look in my tablet and didn't see any security app.

Comment: I didn't notice that, sorry. I have created two different projects using bootcompeted receiver the same way as you did and they both work in android 6.0. I can't tell what is the problem, but it must be your tablet.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. I will then test my code on another tablet to see if I have success.

Comment: I tested on a new tablet (different manufacturer) and it worked! Thanks for the help @Dejvid.